# What does "#" mean in LCOV report?

Tags: lcov

I thought I had covered both cases for the **while** loop, but **brcov** doesn't show 100% due to that "#" alert:

[hash symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfekZ.png)

Answer (score 2):

From the `genhtml` man page:

```
       --branch-coverage
       --no-branch-coverage
              Specify whether to display branch coverage data in HTML output.

              Use --branch-coverage  to  enable  branch  coverage  display  or
              --no-branch-coverage to disable it. Branch coverage data display
              is enabled by default

              When branch coverage display is enabled, each overview page will
              contain  the number of branches found and hit per file or direc‐
              tory, together with the resulting coverage  rate.  In  addition,
              each  source  code view will contain an extra column which lists
              all branches of a line with indications of  whether  the  branch
              was taken or not. Branches are shown in the following format:

               ' + ': Branch was taken at least once
               ' - ': Branch was not taken
               ' # ': The basic block containing the branch was never executed

              Note  that it might not always be possible to relate branches to
              the corresponding source code  statements:  during  compilation,
              GCC  might  shuffle branches around or eliminate some of them to
              generate better code.

              This option can also be configured permanently using the config‐
              uration file option genhtml_branch_coverage.
```

Comment: Can you please add the difference between the Branch was taken vs Branch was not taken?

Comment: Hmm, I would have thought that was evident in the name.  Any time the code can deviate from straight-line flow (if, else, while, do, switch), that involves a branch.  For best coverage, you want some tests that TAKE the branch and some that don't.